# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<double>' to 'double'

Tags: c#, linq

I want to collect the price of all items that have the same item number
But the show this problem
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'double'

How do i correct this?

Heres the code:

```
public double oIlstGetVouchersDetailjh(int nvoucherID)
        {
            Training_sNairoukhEntities1 sNairoukhEntities1 = new Training_sNairoukhEntities1();
            double olstInvoicesSrech = from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
                                       where (Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID)
                                       group Entity by Entity.ItemID into g
                                       select g.Sum(s => s.ItemPrice);

            ret
```

Comment: You are grouping by `ItemID`, so you'd expect a list of sums per grouping item, not just one sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering by ItemID and then grouping. No need for grouping here. Select sum directly:

```
double olstInvoicesSrech = (from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
                            where Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID
                            select Entity.ItemPrice).Sum();
```

If you want to sum up all rows and group them by ItemID then:

```
var olstInvoicesSrech = from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
                        group Entity by Entity.ItemID into g
                        select new { g.Key.ItemID, si =  g.Sum(s => s.ItemPrice) };
```

Comment: thank you  but can i use grouping without filtering 

like this 
double olstInvoicesSrech = from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
                                           group Entity by Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID into g
                                           select g.Sum(s => s.ItemPrice);

                return olstInvoicesSrech;


but i have the same problem

Comment: What do you want to select? Sum of all entries in INV_InventoryItems? Then remove filtering in my answer and you will get sum of all rows

Comment: sum the price item of all items that have the same item id

Comment: That way you get list of sums, how do you expect cast list to double?

Comment: I didnt understand your question
I am a beginner in Programming
Especially linq any way thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly you want sum of ItemPrices of particular item. Then you don't need group and my first query will work. If you want to group by Item and not to filter then you will get list `{ItemID=1, Sum=5}, {ItemID=3, Sum=10}` and this is not castable to double. In this case you can use dynamic type var as in second statement.