# sum of item prices that have the same item id

Tags: c#, linq

I want sum of all item prices in all rows in the database table that have the same item id. I mean the result should be one number and put it on textbox automatically when I choose a specific item id from dropdownlist

How can I do it in linq?

```
public double oIlstGetVouchersDetailjh(int nvoucherID)
{
    Training_sNairoukhEntities1 sNairoukhEntities1 = new Training_sNairoukhEntities1();
    double sum = (from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
                                where Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID
                                select Entity.ItemPrice).sum();
    return sum;
}
```

or

```
public double oIlstGetVouchersDetailjh(int nvoucherID)
{
    Training_sNairoukhEntities1 sNairoukhEntities1 = new Training_sNairoukhEntities1();
    double olstInvoicesSrech = from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
    group Entity by Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID into g
    select g.sum(Entity => Entity.ItemPrice);

    return olstInvoicesSrech;
}
```

but the second query give me this msg   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'double

Comment: What is the output of above query?

Comment: I Didn't  try it 
But how can I put this result into textbox in gridview automatically and 
is the query achieve what I want or need to use group by

Comment: Why you removed your code?

Comment: Why you use Average and not Sum?

Comment: Luna, why are you posting same questions with different users? Here you accepted my answer on exact same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722347/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryabledouble-to-double

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this will work:

```
    Training_sNairoukhEntities1 sNairoukhEntities1 = new Training_sNairoukhEntities1();
    double sum = (from Entity in sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems
                                where Entity.ItemID == nvoucherID
                                select Entity.ItemPrice).Sum(); // Change sum to Sum
    return sum;
```

Here's a simpler way:

```
sNairoukhEntities1.INV_InventoryItems.Where(item => item.ItemID == nvoucherID).Sum(item => item.ItemPrice);
```